# How can I find the match string in pattern(AWK)?

Tags: regex, awk

I have a text file with the pattern **starting '-- Host'** and **ending ';'**, and this pattern occurs so many times in the file as follow:

**-- Host (first) Sid (queen1)**

**-- prince princess#/king 1/1**

**;**

**-- Host (first) Sid (queen2)**

**-- prince princess#/king 2/2**

**;**

**-- Host (first) Sid (queen3)**

**-- dir princess#/king 3/3**

**;**

My desired result is as follow:

**queen1 1/1**

**queen2 2/2**

**queen3 3/3**

With **AWK**, I think I can specify the block including this patten like below.However, I got error in putting the second pattern in pattern.

Can you help me accomplish this requirement? Thanks!

```
BEGIN {
}

/-- Host/,/;/ { /prince/ { print $3 } }

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[ ()]+' '/-- Host/,/;/ { if (/-- Host/) printf "%s ",$5; else if (/prince/) print $4;}' file
queen1 1/1
queen2 2/2
queen3 3/3
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[ ()]+'`

  This tells awk to use any combination of any number of the blanks and parens as the field separator.
- `/-- Host/,/;/`

  This selects just groups of lines that start with `-- Host` and end with `;`.  The commands which follow in braces are only executed for lines in these groups.
- `{ if (/-- Host/) printf "%s ",$5; else if (/prince/) print $4;}`

  If the line contains `-- Host`, then we print its fifth field.  Otherwise, if it contains `prince`, we print its fourth field.

Comment: Perfect! That's really what I wanted to know.